# Why do we need method "putIntegerArrayListExtra" in Intent class

Tags: android, android-intent

When I use the put/get methods in the Intent class, I'm curious about why we need the method - "putIntegerArrayListExtra" in the Intent class?

The Intent class has already had put/get methods for "int array":

```
public int[] getIntArrayExtra (String name)
public Intent putExtra (String name, int[] value)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

So, why do we still need a kind of redundant method - putIntegerArrayListExtra?

However, for double/Doule or float/Float, there is no such method, e.g., "putDouleArrayListExtra".

I'm curious about why Google makes such a design?

Is there any special cases that the putIntegerArrayListExtra method is much better than putExtra (String name, int[] value)?

Is there any special cases about we need to transfer Integer array list to somewhere with the Intent obj?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can pass an ArrayList<E> , where the E type is Serializable, so non-primitive you see

Comment: @notTdar I agree with you. But, converting int to Integer doesn't require too much work, right? Also, why Google doesn't do the same thing for double/Double and float/Float?

Comment: When you deal with objects, they are needed